# How to plot % Running Difference in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-visualization, data-visualization, looker-studio

I'm creating charts in Google Data Studio, but unable to perform row wise aggregations. How would I plot bar/line charts of **" % diff "** of a specific column/value.
***% diff = ((Today - Previous day) / (Today)) X 100***

for example, I have table as shown below with two column *DATE* and *VALUE* and I want to plot date wise ***% Diff*** of VALUE, i.e. for 02-01-2020 i want to plot (900-400)/900 * 100= 55 % , for 03-01-2020 i want to plot (200-900)/200 * 100= -350 %, .... and similarly for all the dates

```
   DATE            VALUE

01-01-2020          400
02-01-2020          900
03-01-2020          200
04-01-2020          700
05-01-2020          400
06-01-2020          800
07-01-2020          900
08-01-2020          500
09-01-2020          800
10-01-2020          900
11-01-2020          600
12-01-2020          400
13-01-2020          400
14-01-2020          200
15-01-2020          300
```